# Web API 2.0 - Custom Date Formatting with JavaScriptConverter

Tags: c#, json, datetime, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I need every DateTime object to be in the basic format of "yyyy-MM-dd".

When I was using JSON.Net to do this, it worked fine by adding the following to the WebApiConfig.cs:

```
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
        new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" });
```

However, I have reworked my controllers to return `IHttpActionResult` and just `return Json(objectToSerialize)`.  Now the date formats are wrong as I assume that's because this is now using the `JavaScriptConverter`.  Let me know if I'm wrong.

How do I convert every DateTime in my serialized object into the format I need?

By default, they are now showing as "1927-01-29T00:00:00" ... I need "1927-01-29".

I've seen some crazy hacks that seem like total overkill (such as [this one](http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2011/12/custom-datetime-json-serialization/)).

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: But do you really need use JavaScriptConverter?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea, which is why I'm asking.  I would prefer a global configuration setting that forces Web API to format ALL dates in this format when serializing objects.  The controller returns `IHttpActionResult` and the return line is `return Json(myObject)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can still use `IHttpActionResult` but what you return is not the correct thing. In your case I believe you can fix it via:

```
return Ok(objectToSerialize);
```

it will keep JSON.NET by default in WebApi and you should have your date formatting kept

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks.  I have to rewrite a lot of my unit tests that expected JsonResult and are now seeing OkNegotiatedContentResult but that's fine.